# Bootstrap regression (spss): bias values very very small, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, bootstrap, bias

My linear regression model does not meet the normality of residuals assumption and the number of participants in each group is not well balanced.

I have n=1370 participants and I included seven variables in the model (four of them are dummy codings of a five-level categorical variable).

I am wondering if it is possible to get the bootstrap bias values that I am obtaining (or whether it is due to something I would do wrong): for most of my variables, the bias values are .000. The other ones are close to .001.  (I'll attach the picture tonight, when the gods of internet will be on my side!)

Answer (score 1):

If the only issue with your linear regression is non-normality of residuals, then this is what one would hope to find. Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem):

> In statistics, the Gauss–Markov theorem, named after Carl Friedrich Gauss and Andrey Markov, states that in a linear regression model in which the errors have expectation zero and are uncorrelated and have equal variances, the best linear unbiased estimator (BLUE) of the coefficients is given by the ordinary least squares (OLS) estimator, provided it exists. Here "best" means giving the lowest variance of the estimate, as compared to other unbiased, linear estimators. The errors do not need to be normal, nor do they need to be independent and identically distributed (only uncorrelated with mean zero and homoscedastic with finite variance).

So your coefficient estimates should be unbiased (and also have the lowest variance of all unbiased linear estimates) if the only issue in your analysis is non-normality of residuals.